# Word VBA Macro Through Powershell

Tags: powershell

The following program runs an Excel VBA macro named "Macro1" from Powershell on a group of files in a folder location "c:\mfolder".  How can I replicate it for a Word VBA macro?

*****runexcel.ps1 ******

```
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\mfolder -Include *.xls -Recurse
Foreach($file in $excelFiles)
{
   $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($file.fullname)
   $worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)
   $excel.Run("Macro1")
   $workbook.save()
   $workbook.close()
}
$excel.quit()
```

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

To open MS Word via Powershell, use the following command:

```
$word = new-object –comobject Word.Application
```

Within your loop, use this to open each file:

```
$doc = $word.documents.open($file.fullname)
```

You should be able to adapt the rest from the script you provided.